# Issue with cocoalumberjack when used along with xmppframework in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xmppframework, cocoalumberjack

facing issue with cocoa lumberjack when it is used along with Xmppframework in project written in swift!. installed xmppframework via pods. got following error,Use of unresolved identifier 'DDLogVerbose’. any suggestions?

Comment: Wtihout any code or more information we can only guess whats going wrong. Please share what you have tried.

Comment: @L.Guthardt i tried integarting xmppframework to my app using pods.xmppframework comes with cocoalumberjack framework which can be used for logging. problem am facing is that there is no api/macros which can be used for logging in swift class files?

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same issue, try to install XMPPFramework by adding following line in podfile

`pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => 'https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git', :branch => 'master'`

Comment: Still same issue. master branch has fix for this?

Comment: master branch has fix for this?this is what i tried earlier m integarting 3.7 version of xmppframwork to my swift app via pods. and trying to use cocoalumberjack which comes along with xmppframework. issue am facing here is  that there is no macros accessible in swift class files to use for logging